# Finding the median of a segment using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I would like to find out the median of each segment within an image.
The first step is to do segmentation. I use the skimage.segmentation as [follows](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html#examples-using-skimage-segmentation-felzenszwalb).

Yet the return mask is in a size of `100*100` instead of `100*100*3`.
I would like to use the numpy func to get the median of each segment, as in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-maskedarray-median-function-python/) example.

Is there an easy way to get it to work?

```
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb, slic, quickshift, watershed

np.random.seed(seed=777)
img = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(100,100, 3))

segments_fz = felzenszwalb(img, scale=100, sigma=0.5, min_size=50)
label_image, num = label(segments_fz, return_num = True)
for i in num: 
    mask_arr = np.ma.masked_array(img, mask = ??? )
    out_arr1 = ma.median(mask_arr, axis = 0)
```

Comment: Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell there is no reason here to use `np.ma.masked_array` . You should instead use [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing), which is a very powerful tool in numpy. Consider the following code

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(low=0, high=255, size=(100,100,3))
mask = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 10, size=(100,100))

for i in range(10):
    median_for_i  = image[(mask == i)].mean()
```

The result of `mask==i` is a boolean array of the same shape as `mask`, with a value `True` where the condition is true, and `False` elsewhere. We then use that boolean mask to index the image. `image[mask==i]` will return an array containing only the values of `image` selected by `mask`. The 2 dimensions that we used to index (shape `(100,100)`) will be flattened into a single dimension.

There is no issue with `image` having shape `(100,100,3)` and `mask` having shape `(100,100)`. We're only indexing the first two dimensions, the last one is preserved. If there are `n` pixels in `mask` with a value `i` then `image[mask==i]` will have shape `(n,3)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use scikit-image [`skimage.measure.regionprops`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.measure.html#regionprops) with the `extra_properties` keyword. This will generally be faster than iterating over the labels and doing `segments == i` because that has to process the *whole* image for each label, whereas regionprops will only process a mask of size equal to the bounding box of the label.

From the docstring under `extra_properties`:

> Add extra property computation functions that are not included with skimage. The name of the property is derived from the function name, the dtype is inferred by calling the function on a small sample. If the name of an extra property clashes with the name of an existing property the extra property will not be visible and a UserWarning is issued. A property computation function must take a region mask as its first argument. If the property requires an intensity image, it must accept the intensity image as the second argument.

So, we can do:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage.segmentation import felzenszwalb
from skimage.measure import regionprops


def intensity_median(mask, intensity_image):
    return np.median(intensity_image[mask], axis=0)


np.random.seed(seed=777)
img = np.random.randint(low=0, high = 255, size=(100,100, 3))

segments_fz = felzenszwalb(img, scale=100, sigma=0.5, min_size=50)
label_image, num = label(segments_fz, return_num = True)
props = regionprops(segments_fz, img, extra_properties=(intensity_median,))
label_to_median = {prop.label: prop.intensity_median for prop in props}
# or
# medians = [prop.intensity_median for prop in props]
```